# How can I compare integer elements of an array in express validator?

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I have an express validator for a 2-length integer array that looks like this.

```
exports.createItem = 
    check("times").exists()
        .withMessage('MISSING').isArray({min: 2, max: 2})
        .withMessage('err'),
    check("times.*").not()
        .isString().isInt(),
    (req,res, next) =>
    {
        validationResult(req,res,next);
    }
];
```

I would like to check that the second integer of the array is bigger than the first one. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it an option do this validation in code? Without using express-validator?

Comment: I would prefer express validator since it's already used in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [custom validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) in order to have access to the array elements

```
check("times").exists().withMessage('MISSING')
    .isArray().withMessage('times is not array')
    .custom((value) => {
        if (!value.every(Number.isInteger)) throw new Error('Array does not contain Integers'); // check that contains Integers
        if (value.length !== 2) throw new Error('Not valid Array Length'); // check length
        if (value[0] > value[1]) throw new Error('First element array is bigger than second'); 
        return true;
    })
```

By the way, `min` and `max` options for the `isArray()` method didn't work for me

Comment: Yes that is what exactly I did before reading your answer and it works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[As dimitris tseggenes said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406101/how-can-i-compare-integer-elements-of-an-array-in-express-validator/61416375#61416375) you can use custom validator in order to have access to the array element, I can add my solution to go through the array, in this case of objects, and be able to verify one of its properties

```
body("array")
    .optional()
    .custom((value) => {
        value.forEach(el => {
            if (el.uid == 0) throw new Error('The el is required');
            return true;
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Return statement does not work inside forEach loops. ;)